# Create/Connect VPN connection through C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, client, vpn

I have a URL, a username, and a password. I want to establish a VPN connection in C# .Net WinForms.

Can you please tell me from where I can get started? Any third party API's ?

Code samples will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Using windows built-in VPN support or a 3rd party app like AnyConnect/OpenVPN?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn?view=winrt-20348

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can launch external application like in this [sample](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/csharpgeneral/thread/4a49aa78-04a3-4fc0-ae6d-421621292617). This probably is easiest way to do it, but it depends on external applications.

Or you can try to use Windows API with some wrapper like [DotRas](http://dotras.codeplex.com/). This could be a bit harder, but you won't have any dependancies on particular external apps.

Comment: It might be a silly question, but can you tell me in which of these references, i can create/define the VPN object dynamically based on the provided URL by the client and then connect it using user/pas ??

Comment: Using VPN Sophos Connect ?

Comment: Updated DotRas link to github: https://github.com/winnster/DotRas

Answer (score 10):

You can use the rasdial executable to accomplish this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "VPNConnectionName VPNUsername VPNPassword");
```

Rasdial is Windows 7.. from memory its RasPhone for XP.

Comment: "VPNConnectionName" : Can i define this object dynamically in C# based on the URL provided by the user ?

Comment: @xtremist it's a string, you can do whatever you want.