# Is there any code example of connect into aws vpn with AWS SDK on .net? C# or VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need that my application be able to connect into an aws vpn using aws sdk, but the docs doesn't show any example of how to set up the connection and i have found no useful help on internet either

Can someone give me an example or something?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SDK is for managing AWS resources, like creating the VPN. It is not used for establishing a connection to the VPN. You would use a [VPN client](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/client-vpn-download/) to establish a connection to the VPN.

Comment: Can i do it from the application side? This whay the users of my software doesn't need to install the vpn client

Comment: @GabrielMelo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913695/create-connect-vpn-connection-through-c-net